# could not extend RecyclerView.Adapter after couple of hours even in new project to

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to extend `RecyclerView.Adapter`  but could not extend it like `RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassAdapterName.ClassAdapterNameViewHolder>` I don't know what happened after couple of hours I could not extend the adapter but i did that before even i tried to make a new project and extend it but seems it is not giving me the option to extend.
Thanks for the help

here is my build gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sensors.device.divicetest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.appolica:flubber:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.nisrulz:easydeviceinfo:2.4.1'


}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what error you are getting and where is your adapter class code ?

Comment: package sensors.device.divicetest.adapters;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class FileListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FileListAdapter.> {
    
    
}

i attached a screen shoot to

http://i.imgur.com/bvzfZYW.png
please take a look

Comment: Have you tried `RecyclerView.Adapter<FileListAdapter.ViewHolder> { }` ?

Comment: this is what am not getting like after RecyclerView.Adapter<FileListAdapter. am not getting the ViewHolder>

Comment: This is happening because there is no ViewHolder class in FileListAdapter (which you're supposed to Implement on your own.)
From next time onwards. extend RecyclerView.Adapter and later replace it once you've implemented your ViewHolder class.

Comment: Thanks man @sHOLE like i forget to do that and am roaming here & there to make it correct ..

u can make this in Add ans so that i can make ur ans correct .

Comment: Glad to help. Shall add all this in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, you're specifying FileListAdapter in the `ViewHolder` part of the extension, hence it will search for the ViewHolder in your Adapter class (which you haven't done)

Ideally, while implementing Adapter classes, you should first extend the class as `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` and once you've implemented your own ViewHolder class, replace it in every mentions of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

Answer (score 2):

As sHOLE said, You don't have a `ViewHolder` class inside the adapter.  You can do as following:

```
public class FileListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FileListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

       public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
           public ViewHolder(View v) {
           // initiate your views
           }
       } 

       @Override
       public FileListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

           View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_layout, parent, false);

           ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

           return vh;
       }  


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

what i forget is, to add AdapterViewHolder which extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder

thanks to @sHOLE
first i had to add this

```
public class FileListAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public FileListAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
```

then extend to

```
public class FileListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FileListAdapter.FileListAdapterViewHolder> {

    public class FileListAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public FileListAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```